# Is there anyway to measure run-time of Arduino loop? Is it possible to set concurrent timer?

Tags: timer, arduino, arduino-uno

I need to measure if there is a delay or not on outpu of arduino. It is needed to be 1 sec intervals. Therefore, I would like to measure running time between samples and also call data for each instead of receiving them anyway

Comment: Just use `millis`. Something like "blink without delay" example.

Answer (score 2):

just plump this somewhere in your loop to measure updates per second, at the end I would suggest.

```
static long a;
Serial.println(String(1000 / (millis() - a)) + "UPS");
a = millis();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty simple program using the [millis](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/millis/) function. You could also setup a timer and an ISR.

```
unsigned long startMillis;
unsigned long currentMillis;
const unsigned long period = 1000 // 1000 ms = 1s

void setup()
{
    startMillis = millis();  //initial start time
}

void loop()
{
      currentMillis = millis();
      if (currentMillis - startMillis >= period)
      {
          /* Do stuff */
          startMillis = currentMillis;
      }
}
```